# Проблема парсинга сайта на python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

написал тестовый код :

```
import requests
import pyautogui
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
seperator='.'
url = 'https://soundcloud.com/digitalstreams/sets/chilltrap'
page= requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
#print(soup.findAll('h2'))
music_list =soup.findAll(attrs={'itemprop':"url"}) #парсинг 
music_len=(len(music_list)) #количество элементов
print(page.text)
clear_name=[]

i=1
for clear_name in music_list:
    i=i+1
    if music_list[i]!=None:
        music_list[i]=(seperator.join(music_list[i]))#очистка результата 
        music_list[i]='j!play ' + music_list[i]
        pyautogui.write(music_list[i])#написание результата
        pyautogui.press('enter')#ввод результата 
        print(music_list[i])#проверка на корректность 
        if i==music_len-1:
            break
```

И хотел что бы он парсил все песни(или хоть бы 20) из плейлиста soundcloud.
Но парсит он только первых 5 (замена плейлиста не помогает) 
.
И желательно сделать это без Soundcloud api .
Я новенький и код плохой.

Comment: Там небось через JavaScript список потом ещё подгружается?

Comment: нет , и я повторюсь что я новичок .

Comment: Ну как нет, если да :)  Если посмотреть исходник страницы, то там 5 элементов всего в ней и есть. А дальше видимо скрипты подгружают контент и модифицируют страницу на ходу. Тут либо Selenium нужен, чтобы эмулировать веб-браузер, либо разбираться в скриптах, чтобы самому контент подгружать.

Comment: спасибо   тебе <3